# Unable to find the place in google map using Android in specific radius

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to find places of interest under a specific radius using Android. I am working in this way

```
 String uri = "geo:"+ 40.007620 + "," + -75.160264 +"&q=child hospitals";
                startActivity(new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri)));
```

But when I run the application, It opens the google maps but does not mark the `child hospitals`. Any wrong here?

Comment: Please check this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: @HareshChhelana No radius property given on above link

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("geo:<40.007620>,<-75.160264>?q=<40.007620>,<-75.160264>(child hospitals)"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It finds only one child hospital. I want multiple in specific radius.

Comment: Where should I use it? After parsing? What about radius?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("geo:<40.007620>,<-75.160264>?q=" +  Uri.encode("child hospitals")));
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: Find more options here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: Methew What about the radius? For example I want with in 2km.

Comment: I want to see all `child hospitals` in specific radius.  How can I add the radius?

Comment: No radius property is in above link.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below reference which will guide you to how to pass or format map intent query data :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Example :

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:40.007620,-75.160264?q=" + Uri.encode("child hospitals"));
```

Comment: I want `child Hospitals` specific radius . How can I give the radius in query?

Answer (score 0):

Humty you can try to this code hope this can help you..

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:40.007620,-75.160264?z=10&q=child hospitals");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Comment: I want to see all `child hospitals` in specific radius.  How can I add the radius?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
String urlAddress = 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,lng&radius=500&type=city hospital&keyword=hospital&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

which you can pass to

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will get opened in Google Maps with the results w.r.t provided radius. It works also same mentioned in below doc reference.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

**Url to test :**

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=18.590478,73.727191&radius=50000&type=child%20hospital&keyword=child%20hospital&key=PASTE_YOUR_API_KEY